# TexLive lost fonts after a reboot; mktexmf is trying to access a wrong folder

Tags: windows, cyrillic, texmf, texlive-2018

I installed `scheme-full` of TexLive, and everything was okay until I rebooted my PC. Then all cyrillic fonts went missing, and `mktexmf` started printing such messages during the build (question marks denote cyrillic characters):

```
name = larm1000, rootname = larm, pointsize = 1000
mkdir C:/Users/????????? error.
Failed to access C:/Users/?????????/.texlive2018/texmf-var.
Cannot get destination directory name.
```

During the installation I changed `TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX` and set the codepage to 65001.

`TEXDIR` is `C:\Programs\texlive\2018`.

How can I point `mktexmf` to a correct directory?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Which editor do you use?

Comment: Hello, I use TeXstudio, but it's not the source of the problem. I could reproduce the issue manually running `mktexmf larm1000.mf` in `cmd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked TexLive's variables listed at http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-100002.3, and `TEXMFVAR` was pointing to the wrong location. Setting it to `%TEXDIR%\texmf-var` using `tlmgr conf texmf` fixed the issue